# In cristijora/vue-form-wizard, is there a way to programmatically advance to next step

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use the cristijora/vue-form-wizard and cannot deduce through the documentation if there is a way to advance to the next step via code. In a step I have logic that checks if a record exists and MAY require additional information from the user if it doesn't ... therefore, I want to advance programmatically if record exists to avoid the second request for info.

I am hoping someone with greater vue.js knowledge is actually using this package and can help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, but from a short look, aren't you passing a step property? can't you just advance the step property ? (i.e. step++)

Comment: not passing a step prop

Comment: <form-wizard title="" subtitle="" color="#0F75BC"
                         @on-complete="onComplete"></form-wizard>

Comment: but it does allow you to pass one so maybe that's the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is only possible with **internal component methods**:

First of all, you will need to add **ref** ([reference ID](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)) to the form-wizard component inside your template:

```
<template>
    <form-wizard ref="wizard">
    ...
```

Then in you can start using it in your component.
Here is an example what will navigate you to the second step:

```
mounted(){
    //this is needed to unlock step
    this.$refs.wizard.maxStep = 1
    this.$refs.wizard.navigateToTab(1)     
}
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/Evgalak/1jt9wkyt/)

More info about internal methods could be found in [here](http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=methods).

Answer (score 0):

this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0,3)

Where 3 is the next tab you want. Tab starts at number 0

Answer (score 0):

An old question but just incase someone needs the answer to this, to go to the next tab you can use the below

```
      this.$refs.wizard.nextTab();
```

This will remove the need to define the step number you wish to go to